# Can knowledge act as a trigger?

Tags: psychosomatic-illness

I watched House Season 1, Episode 2 and it mentions a myoclonic jerk, I looked it up online and a couple weeks later, I started having one just before sleep. It's irregular, that is, not every night but it got me thinking. I've never had any myoclonic jerks before now.

Can knowing of a psychological/physiological condition cause it?

Or am I suffering from a suffer case of *post hoc ergo propter hoc*?
Is there such common a thing as sudden-onset adolescent myoclonic jerks?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). There is a discrepancy between the title and the body of your question. Placebo effect is a beneficial effect of a treatment, based on patient's belief, and the body of the question seems to be about [experiencing symptoms that you read about](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Hypochondriasis+in+Medical+Students). That being said, the question seems to be asking for personalized advice - if you edit it to make it a bit more general, you will make sure that it remains on-topic.

Comment: My apologies, I do not know the correct terminology for this field.

Comment: Additionally, each question is stand-alone answerable assuming that you take into account my case.

Comment: Thank you though. This does seem to fit. Do you know or know where I can learn whether this psychosomatic symptom will persist?

Comment: That's just the thing - I can't tell whether it is psychosomatic or not, nor can I make any prognosis. Firstly, this sort of thing cannot be done on-line, it has to be done by a physician in person (this is why personal medical advice is [off-topic](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here), and secondly it isn't my area of expertise. I just wanted to clarify what your question is about - I didn't try to make a diagnosis, because I can't. As for the terminology - don't worry, that's what comments are for - to clarify a question when something is unclear.

Comment: That's quite alright. I'm not worried and it isn't having any adverse or detrimental effect on my ability to function. I was just curious. A somewhat extrapolative case-study you might say.

Comment: Extrapolating to general psychology that is.

Comment: Most likely, you've had them and never noticed because you didn't know what they were. Like seeing the new car you just looked at all over the roads suddenly.